# Avoid cutting off of my labels in parcats trace

Tags: r, plotly

How can I avoid that my labels are cutoff in this plotly chart?

```r
library(plotly)
dd <- data.frame(from = c("Super Super Super Long Title", "A"), 
                   to = c("B", "Also very very long title"))
plot_ly(dd) %>% 
  add_trace(type = "parcats", 
            dimensions = list(list(values = ~ from), 
                              list(values =  ~ to)))
```

[image: plotly chart where the labels left and right of the categories are cut off]

I tried to add `layout(yaxis = list(automargin = TRUE))` but to no avail (I guess the borders are technically not axes.

Ideally, I am looking for a solution, which does not require manually fiddling with values, as the chart will be part of a Shiny app, where I have no control over the final labels.

Any other neat tricks like abbreviating the labels and showing them in the hover, are appreciated, but I would be really curious to learn how to auto-adapt the margins to incorporate all of my plot.

---

Adding manually some margin solves it for this plot, but as said I am looking for an automated version (that is, if I could find a way to calculate a proper margin, I would also happily accept this answer):

```r
plot_ly(dd) %>% 
  add_trace(type = "parcats", 
            dimensions = list(list(values = ~ from), 
                              list(values =  ~ to))) %>% 
  layout(margin = list(l = 120, r = 90))
```

[image: same plot as before but with manually enlarged margins on the left and the right]

Comment: While there is no great method, you can wrap the strings. Since that doesn't quite answer your question I didn't add it as an answer. If you would like, I can add it. Just let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am indeed curious would you mind adding that as an answeR?

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions about my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the strings before or after you plot. I've provided a way to execute either of these options. If you run into any problems, let me know. Either option produces the same result.

##### Option 1

*Wrapping strings with line breaks before graphing.*

In the `lapply`, I've set it to look at every row within every column and wrap long strings every 15 characters. This won't break up a word, so up to 15 characters.

If 15 characters are too many or not enough, it only occurs one time in the function so it's easy to change: `strwrap(..., 15)`

```
library(plotly)
dd <- data.frame(from = c("Super Super Super Long Title", "A"), 
                 to = c("B", "Also very very long title"))

# option 1 - wrap text before graphing
invisible(lapply(1:ncol(dd), function(j) {  # for every column
  lapply(1:nrow(dd), function(k) {          # for every row
    dd[j, k] <<- paste0(strwrap(dd[j, k], 15), collapse = "<br />")
  })                                        # break long strings with line breaks
}))

plot_ly(dd) %>% 
  add_trace(type = "parcats", 
            dimensions = list(list(values = ~ from), 
                              list(values =  ~ to))) %>% 
  layout(margin = list(l = 50, r = 50))
```

##### Option 2

*Wrapping strings with line breaks after graphing.*

In this option, I've used a UDF that modifies the plot after it's built. This is simply called along with your graph. If you had multiple colors, this may need some adjustment. (Let me know if you need me to revisit it for that reason...or any other reason.)

Like the previous option, this one is set to 15 characters before wrapping the string, as well.

```
# option 2 - wrap text after graphing
wrapper <- function(plt) {
  plt <- plotly_build(plt)           # go to where the labels are, for each label
  lapply(1:length(plt$x$data[[1]]$dimensions), function(k) {
    lapply(1:length(plt$x$data[[1]]$dimensions[[k]]$values), function(j) {
      xx <- plt$x$data[[1]]$dimensions[[k]]$values[[j]]
      yy <- paste0(strwrap(xx, 15), collapse = "<br />")
      plt$x$data[[1]]$dimensions[[k]]$values[[j]] <<- yy
    })                                    # break long strings with line breaks
  })
  plt   # return the modified plot
}
dd <- data.frame(from = c("Super Super Super Long Title", "A"), 
                 to = c("B", "Also very very long title"))
plot_ly(dd) %>% 
  add_trace(type = "parcats", 
            dimensions = list(list(values = ~ from), 
                              list(values =  ~ to))) %>% 
  layout(margin = list(l = 50, r = 50)) %>% 
  wrapper()                                    # <--- calling the UDF!
```

[image]

Comment: I like the idea of the post built option, because my gut feeling tells me that potentially I could use some of `plt's` slots to determine whether there is  a cut off label and by how much it is cut off to determine a sensible value for `strwrap`. Out of the top of your head, do you know some potential slots whihc could help me here?

Comment: I have to ask for clarification. What do you mean by slot? Are you talking about the margins?

Comment: I was wondering whether there is some list element in the nested `plt` list, which could be used to help here?

Comment: All the list elements could help in some way. I'm not trying to be difficult, I'm just not sure what you mean. Help with what aspect? The fit? The available space? Something else?